# EE Store 2 and paid UPS extension seems to be broken

Tags: expresso-store, extension, shipping, ups-shipping

I am trying to implement the UPS Shipping Extension purchased and it appears to be broken. I've uploaded the extension, enabled it, entered in the Access Key, User ID and Password. I've setup the shipping options and entered in the source destination. Based on previous issues found here, I've made sure the country is "US".

Within my template I've added {field:shipping_method} in the checkout tag. All I get is an empty drop down. The UPS account exists and is set up as a personal account with one access key generated.

I'm using Store 2.04 and UPS extension 1.02

I'm out of options here. I can't even troubleshoot anymore. Where did things break in this super basic setup I have?

Comment: You need to make sure that you show shipping options after you have collected the users shipping address. Also it is a good rule of thumb to clear your cart if you make any changes in the CP, to make sure you are starting with a fresh session. Do the products all have weights and dimensions set in the publish/edit pages? You are also 3-4 version behind the latest version of Store 2.2 which can make troubleshooting more difficult.

Comment: My products do have a weight and dimensions entered. Double checked to make sure 'free shipping' wasn't enabled. I just updated to the latest version of 2.2. I cleared my cart and cache. I uninstalled the UPS extension and re-installed. I've double checked that it's getting the shipping information. It's still coming up as blank. Boy, oh boy.

Comment: Can you please post some template snippets of the address entry step and the next step where the shipping options field is shown?

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for getting back with me. I *just* located the issue. It was how the state was being passed. I had an issue with how the states auto populate when the country is selected. Problem is solved now.

Comment: @RobertE Can you post your fix as an answer below and select it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above:

> I just located the issue. It was how the state was being passed. I had an issue with how the states auto populate when the country is selected. Problem is solved now.